# Как получить значение из @property внутри класса?

Tags: python

Есть класс `foo` и метод этого класса `fuu`, в котором я хочу использовать `_obj` как параметр по умолчанию.

```py
class foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self._obj = "test"

    @property
    def obj(self):
        return self._obj

    @obj.setter
    def obj(self,val):
        self._obj = val

    def fuu(self, val = obj):
        return val + "test"
```

К сожалению, при вызове метода `fuu()` мне выпадает исключение:

```py
>>> s = foo()
>>> s.obj
'test'
>>> s.fuu()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
    s.fuu()
  File "/Users/r2d2/Desktop/asda.py", line 14, in fuu
    return val + "gfhjfjh"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'property' and 'str'
```

Как мне получить значение из property(?) или какую хитрость применить, чтобы объекты, которые я инициализирую в классе, я мог использовать как параметры по умолчанию для методов внутри этого класса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исправьте fuu вот так:

```
def fuu(self, val = None):
    val = val or self.obj
    return val + "test"
```

Просто чтобы получить значение property, нужно вызвать его от self. А в аргументе по умолчанию self указать не получится. Поэтому его вызывать можно только внутри метода, где self уже есть.

Но вообще, это выглядит как-то очень переусложнено. Если внутри fuu вам нужен self._obj, то прямо так его и вызывайте. Зачем вам для этого ещё и property?

```
class foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self._obj = "test"

    # Property не нужно,
    # обошлись и без него

    def fuu(self, val = None):
        val = val or self._obj
        return val + "test"

s = foo()
print(s.fuu())
```